# Popup notification similar to Facebook in Drupal

Tags: jquery, drupal-7, popup

For a Drupal 7 project, I need to show popup notifications like those shown in facebook. For example, if at any point of time 3 users A, B & C are logged in to drupal website and user A makes a comment anywhere in site then user B & C should see a popup notification without having to refresh the page. Just like facebook notifications keep popping up.

I am using rules module to find out when someone comments. I was able to show the notification using one jquery notification plugin however for that to work, you need to refresh the page and that plugin shows the notification to same user who commented instead of showing it to other logged in users.

Answer (score 1):

you could do this with AJAX. jQuery has [some helpful functions](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for that. So make a php file that checks if there is a new comment that applies to the current user and let it return true (or the amount of comments). Then fetch that using javascript (for example every second) and display the popup.

Ajax and google are your friend here! Good luck!

Comment: Thanks! Actually I have thought about this but I don't want to go with continuous polling. I am looking for a cleaner and leaner solution which is triggered only when needed and no polling or checks are needed.

Comment: Hey Vikram, you should read up on Comet or Sockets then. I made my first long polling script using node.js though. Its very easy and gives you callbacks when, and only when there is something to report.